# Setting up OpenGL library on windows

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, cmake, glut

I'm totally new to OpenGL, so I'm trying to compile my application at home. At my university I have everything settle by my professor in the lab and there I use Linux. At home I'm using windows 8 with visual studio 2013.

I'm trying to build a sphere in my app which contain the includes below:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
```

So, since it contains Glut.h I went to http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php#2 to download the library and make it rock, but I had some problems.

I thought the windows version would come compiled and it didn't. The dlls are not inside the package as I expected to link them in my project properties so I tryed to use CMake to compile the glut but it didn't work. CMake returns to me the following log:

```
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: C:/Program Files/Glut 3.7 Build/CMakeCache.txt.tmp
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Program Files/Glut 3.7/glut-3.7" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. C:/Program Files/Glut 3.7 Build/CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
```

It says that the folder doesn't contain the CMake file.

My download link to glut (supposed to be windows, not sure cos of the error) is this http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut37.zip

Normally I programm java, which I dont have so many headaches to setup the IDE..so take it easy please and now I ask:

What am I missing to make my OpenGL code run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your teacher should help you at the first place.

I would like to inform you that GLUT library was abandoned since 1998. Last version is [3.7].But you are lucky!

"**freeglut**" is alternative to the OpenGL Utility Toolkit (GLUT) library.
Everything you need is [here](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/), I recommend reading it all.

And to help you out, [here](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/) you can find Windows binaries, look for link called: "**Download freeglut 2.8.1-1 for MSVC**".

After download, you must link the **library** folder, **include** folder and copy freeglut.dll to you project folder (inside Debug or Release folder). You can find dll files inside a **bin** folder.
And after that, you can call  `#include "GL/glut.h"` with no problems.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't compile with CMake. Open a Visual Studio command prompt and type `nmake` in the top level directory of the glut source code.

Answer (score -1):

> At my university I have everything settle by my professor in the lab and there I use Linux. At home I'm using windows 8 with visual studio 2013.

Then the very first thing you absolutely *must* do is heading to your GPU maker's website, download the newest drivers from there and install them. That is, because the drivers installed by default with Windows 8 lack proper OpenGL functionality.

> So, since it contains `Glut.h`

You mean `glut.h` – file names are case sensitive on most operating systems (Windows not among them). So for portability reasons you should care to write them with the proper spelling.

> I went to http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php#2 to download the library

The old GLUT library isn't maintained for over a decade. Use an alternative implementation like [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) and use that.

> so I tryed to use CMake to compile the glut but it didn't work.

Okay, here you got no technical problem, but a lack of understanding. Essentially your brain got what I call "IDE rot": All those sugar coating and clicky-pointy action of IDEs obscure what actually is going on when a program is built. You'll have to bit the bullet there and understand how the interaction between the *build control generators* the *build system* the *compiler* and the *linker* works.

CMake is a *build control generator*: In CMake you describe the build dependencies of your program sources. From that CMake generates the actual build information for the *build system* used (GNU make and GCC on Linux; NMake and MSVC++ compiler on Windows for example).

Of course for CMake to work there must be an appropriate CMake configuration present. And in the case of GLUT that's definitely not there (the last official release of GLUT predates the first release of CMake.

Now you should really wonder: Why did you call "cmake" in the first place? I bet, because you always did it so far, or you read it somewhere, without even trying to understand what's going on.

What you did was folloing a [Cargo Cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_science) – it somehow resembles the actual process, it looks like it from the outside, but it doesn't yield results. Feynman's speech later coined the term [Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming); interesting enough I was using that term (consistently with its definition, just due to being familiar with Feynman's speech) without knowing that other people already had coined it in exactly the same way. Such a often it happens, that people will come up independently with the same term for it.

> Normally I programm Java, which I don't have so many headaches to setup the IDE

Well, that's your problem right there. You only know how to click around in an IDE. Even when programming Java, with an IDE, you should get intimately familiar with the actual build process: Java compiler, JAR file creating, and so on.

> What am I missing to make my OpenGL code run?

I bet not very much. It's a lack of understanding how the build process for software works and is controlled. You'll have to bite the bullet and learn that first. And for that I suggest you install Linux or FreeBSD, or at least Cygwin on your computer.

Windows is not a very good system to learn those things, because its been built around clicky GUIs. That is not to say that Windows was a bad operating system. It's juat that you want to have something you can experiment with and quickly go through various iterations of build tool option switches. A GUI can't give you that.

Comment: There's no difference between Linux' shell and Windows' command prompt. Both are command line interfaces and you can invoke the compiler and build tools from the command line just as easy on Windows. In fact, when you install Visual Studio it also installs **fully configured** command prompts, ready to go. If anything, it's probably easier to compile from the command line on Windows with Visual Studio installed.

Comment: @IInspectable: That's a bad joke, isn't it? The standard Windows `cmd.exe` command prompt is a bad joke compared to a real Unix-eqsque shell. In Windows you'd have to use the PowerShell to come even close. If you don't perceive a difference between a shell like zsh or bash and Windows' cmd.exe you definitely didn't **use** a real shell.

Comment: With respect to calling `gcc` or `cl` there really is no difference, or `make` and `nmake`/`msbuild` for that matter. And that's really all you need to compile from the command line, to learn things. If you disagree you need to expand your answer to include **why** *nix is a better system to build a solid foundation on build basics.

Comment: @IInspectable: Other people did this already. Far better than I could and much more elaborate: http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/series/unix-as-ide/ – http://www.slideshare.net/tkramar/unix-is-my-ide#btnNext – http://michaelochurch.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/ide-culture-vs-unix-philosophy/

Comment: You changed the subject. The subject you covered in your answer was *How to learn about the build process*. And you still have not provided profound evidence of why \*nix is better at this. The links you provided explain how to set up a shell for use as an IDE (replacement). But we're still at the *Do not use an IDE just yet* stage. Given that the OP already has a fully configured command line based build system in place your advice to go through a **lot** of trouble to get another one is misguided and unfounded.

Comment: @IInspectable: CMake comes with a GUI. Anyway, to understand what tools like `make`, `nmake`, `SCons` and similar are doing, it is of great benefit to understand how the single parts of a project build are chained together. `make` for example tightly integrates with the shell; every command is passed to the shell, it uses shell parameter evaluation and such.

Comment: @IInspectable: For example, if you don't have a make system in place you could as well use the following: `CFLAGS=$(pkg-config --cflags …) LDFLAGS=$(pkg-config --ldflags … ) cd build; for s in $(find ../ -iname '*.c') ; do cc ${CFLAGS} -c $s ; done ; cc -o execuable *.o ${LDFLAGS}` – with only a little more effort you could make it recompile only those source files that were modified. The point is: Using a shell you can create our own little toy build system, which is great to understand what is going on behind the curtain of fully fledged build utilities.

Comment: We both agree that learning to use the build tools at the command line is beneficial. You are still failing to provide profound evidence why the OP's already installed build system is less suited as a learning tool. Provide that or remove the unfounded opinion and misguided advice from your proposed answer.

Comment: @IInspectable: Just so much: OP has Visual Studio installed but mindlessly went ahead and used *CMake* trying to build GLUT. This demonstrates a fundamental lack of understanding how the pieces come together. The problem is, that using an IDE you got a pretty facade, but you don't learn what's going on behind it. If however you're working on the command line, then you can access each tool directly. First you do every step manually. To speed things up you make use of the shell's functionality. After working some time with the CLI you get an understanding through which steps a build system goes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40055/discussion-between-iinspectable-and-datenwolf)